# Cómo hacer que una imagen respete el tamaño de la pantalla

Tags: html, css

Estoy armando una página plana con html y css más una animación.

Es una página simple con un background y una imagen en el centro que es un png sin fondo, y la imagen es un espiral que gira en el centro de la página.

Lo que quiero lograr es que la imagen gire, dando un efecto con el espiral, pero el png debe ser más grande que la pantalla, y quisiera que no me agrande la página ni me genere las barras de scroll, ya que al hacerlo, me queda una parte del background en blanco y se pierde el efecto esperado.

```css
html,
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: url('https://image.freepik.com/vector-gratis/fondo-rayo-espiral-blanco-negro_1164-1771.jpg');
}

#giro {
  animation: giro infinite 20s linear;
}

@keyframes giro {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}

.logo {
  width: 900px;
  height: 900px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>document</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/images/favicon/favicon.png">

</head>

<body>
  <nav></nav>
  <img class="logo" id="giro" src="https://image.freepik.com/vector-gratis/fondo-rayo-espiral-blanco-negro_1164-1771.jpg" alt="">

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Si la página no va a superar nunca el alto del viewport agrega esto al body

```
body {overflow: hidden;}
```

```css
html,
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  
  display: flex;
  background: url('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/f3/f4/41/f3f441018b10739dd05c9fe9ad864bec.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  
}

#giro {
  animation: giro infinite 20s linear;
}

@keyframes giro {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}

.logo {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  border: 2px dashed black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>document</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/images/favicon/favicon.png">

</head>

<body>
  <nav></nav>
  <img class="logo" id="giro" src="https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/001/192/060/non_2x/circle-logo-spiral-png.png" alt="">

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Me permití agregar un snippet para que pudiera ver lo que dices funcionando

Answer (score 0):

Como dice Elboy, puedes agregar un `overflow: hidden` a tu body y estirar tu imagen a un 200% por ejemplo, pero difícilmente se vera bien, por la calidad de la imagen y por que no creo que se ajuste correctamente, ahora bien, podrías utilizar [canvas](/questions/tagged/canvas) y [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), quedara mejor y será mas fácil de manipular, por ejemplo, crea un html con lo siguiente:

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        
        <canvas></canvas>
    
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
              margin: 0;
              overflow: hidden;
              padding: 0;
            }
    
            body:hover {
              cursor: pointer;
            }
    
            .info {
              font-family: sans-serif;
              color: black;
              position: absolute;
              font-weight: bold;
              font-size: large;
              text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black;
              opacity: 0;
              transition: all 0.5s ease;
            }
    
            body:hover > .info {
              opacity: 0.75;
            }
    
        </style>
    
        <script type="text/javascript">
            class Uzumaki {
              constructor(
                lineWidth = 30,
                maxFactor = 1.2,
                start = 0,
                startIncrement = -0.2
              ) {
                this.canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
                this.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
                this.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
                this.center = {
                  x: this.canvas.width / 2,
                  y: this.canvas.height / 2
                };
                this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
                this.ctx.lineWidth = this.lineWidth = lineWidth;
                this.ctx.lineCap = this.lineCap = "round";
                this.maxFactor = maxFactor;
                this.start = start;
                this.startIncrement = startIncrement;
              }
              draw() {
                if (
                  this.canvas.width !== window.innerWidth ||
                  this.canvas.height !== window.innerHeight
                ) {
                  this.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
                  this.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    
                  this.ctx.lineWidth = this.lineWidth;
                  this.ctx.lineCap = this.lineCap;
                } else {
                  this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
                }
    
                let max = Math.max(this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height) * this.maxFactor;
                this.ctx.beginPath();
                let t = this.start;
                let x, y;
                let a = 1;
                let r;
                for (let i = 0; i < max; ++i) {
                  r = i * a;
                  x = r * Math.cos(t) + this.center.x;
                  y = r * Math.sin(t) + this.center.y;
                  this.ctx.lineTo(x, y);
                  t += 0.1;
                }
                this.ctx.stroke();
                this.start += this.startIncrement;
              }
              toggleDir() {
                this.startIncrement *= -1;
              }
              display() {
                let animate = () => {
                  requestAnimationFrame(animate); 
                  this.draw();
                };
                requestAnimationFrame(animate);
              }
    
              run() {
                this.display();
                this.canvas.addEventListener(
                  "click", () => false
                );
              }
            }
    
            (() => {
              let spiral = new Uzumaki();
              spiral.run();
            })();
        </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Creara el mismo efecto pero basado en canvas, por lo que será mas fácil de manipular, ejemplo sacado de https://codepen.io/jrcharney/pen/LYRPOaE

Si aun quieres usar una imagen prueba con esto

```
html,
    body {
        overflow: hidden;
      min-height: 100vw;
      min-width: 100vh;
      height: 100vh;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

   .logo {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      margin: auto;
      display: block;
      margin-top: -25%;
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
    }
```